# What does it mean to call a Java method using "new" in a statement?

Tags: java

Say, I have a code snippet like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().myFunction();
    }
```

Where myFunction is another method (could be non-static) defined in the same class as Main. Why would you do the above? Why not just do: `myFunction();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myFunction` is an instance method that belongs to the type `Main`. What your code does is that it first creates a new instance of type `Main` (i.e. `new Main()`) and then invokes the method `myFunction` on that instance.

A more verbose version of your code would be:

```
Main mainObj = new Main();
mainObj.myFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely myFunction is a instance method and not a class (static) method, therefore must be called on an instance of the class. Since you are inside a static method, you can not directly call instance methods, you must create an instance first which is what `new Main()` does, then you can call it.

Answer (score 1):

> *What does it mean to call a Java method using “new” in a statement?*

It creates a new instance of the given class

> *Why not just do: myFunction();*

Most likely `myFunction()` is an instance method:

```
public void myFunction() { 
    ....
}
```

In order to invoke an **instance** method, you need an instance **first**.

Using the `new` keyword creates a new object and then it invokes the `myFunction` method on that object.

Methods marked with the `static` access modifier are **class** methods, they belong to the whole class and don't need an instance to work.

Methods who are not marked as `static` do need an instance to work.

That's what the compiler error:

> *...cannot invoke a non-static method from a static context...*<sup>1</sup>

is all about.

<sup>1</sup><sub>or something like that</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Well, "Main" is a class, and 'main' is a method, so they are not the same thing.  If you wanted to create a new instance of the "Main" class and call the myFunction method you would do as your example shows.  Now, if "main" is a method of "Main"... then I can't say *why* you would actually do such a thing.

Comment: `main` is `static`.  If `myFunction` is not, you cannot simply call `myFunction()`.

Comment: @ephemient: "if" being the key word.  We don't know what any of the other code is doing.

Comment: @Alexander Pogrebnyak: Yes, I was trying to say the *I* don't know why because *I* can't see the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Main().myFunction();
```

This creates a new instance of the `Main` class and then invokes the `myFunction()` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

its because myFunction() is non static, so you need an instance of the class Main to call it.

new Main().myFunction();

can be broken down into

new Main() // instantiate first, then only
.myFunction()